# Solidity function returning large json object

Tags: solidity, web3js

So I have a basic function call in Solidity that returns a string

```
function getString() constant returns (string) {
  return "hello";
}
```

I call it using web3 after instantiating the contract

```
const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
  from: applicationAccount.address,
  gasPrice: '20000000',
  gas: 4711489
});

async function getString() {
  let hash = await Contract.methods.getString.call()
  return hash;
}
```

The object returned is a large object describing the contract, when all I want returned is the string `hello`

```
{ call: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
send: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
encodeABI: [Function: bound _encodeMethodABI],
estimateGas: [Function: bound _executeMethod],
arguments: [],
_method:
 { constant: true,
 inputs: [],
 name: 'getString',
 outputs: [ [Object] ],
 payable: false,
 stateMutability: 'view',
 type: 'function',
 signature: '0xb96d1702' },
```

How can I return the string `hello`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
await Contract.methods.getString().call()
```

Comment: this ends up returning `undefined`